# How to call a function from a shortcode function in an oop plugin

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, oop

I’m developing an OOP plugin based on [WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate by Devin Vinson](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate).
In the includes folder, I’ve created a class for shortcodes:

```
class My_Plugin_Shortcodes {

    public static function foo_shortcode( $atts ) {
        
        // get parameters
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'arg1' => '',
            'arg2' => '',
        ), $atts );
        
        // do something
        
        return $myFooVar;
        
    }   
        
    public static function bar_shortcode( $atts ) {
        
        // get parameters
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'arg3' => '',
            'arg4' => '',
        ), $atts );
        
        // do something
        
        return $myBarVar;
        
    }   
    
}
```

The shortcodes are added in the primary plugin class, also in the includes folder:

```
class My_Plugin {

    public function __construct() {

        ...
        
        $this->load_shortcodes();
        
        ...
        
    }
    
    ...

    private function load_shortcodes() {

        $plugin_shortcodes = new My_Plugin_Shortcodes();

        add_shortcode( 'foo', array( $plugin_shortcodes, 'foo_shortcode' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'bar', array( $plugin_shortcodes, 'bar_shortcode' ) );
    
    
    }

}
```

So far, so good.

But a large part of what happens in `Foo` is identical to a large part of what happens in `Bar`, and I want to place the common code in a (subroutine) function that can be called by both `Foo` and `Bar`.  Procedurally, that might look like this:

```
class My_Plugin_Shortcodes {

    public function foo_bar_subroutine( $a ) {
        
        // do something
        
        return $mySubVar;
        
    }   
        
    public static function foo_shortcode( $atts ) {
        
        // get parameters
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'arg1' => '',
            'arg2' => '',
        ), $atts );
        
        // do something
        
        $myFooVar = foo_bar_subroutine( $a )
        
        return $myFooVar;
        
    }   
        
    public static function bar_shortcode( $atts ) {
        
        // get parameters
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'arg3' => '',
            'arg4' => '',
        ), $atts );
        
        // do something
        
        $myBarVar = foo_bar_subroutine( $a )
        
        return $myBarVar;
        
    }   
    
}
```

which doesn't work because it doesn't follow OOP conventions.  But I don't know how to set it up to follow both OOP conventions and WP conventions.  I assume that the subroutine doesn't get declared by either `add_shortcode` or `add_action`. But, if not, how does it get in?

Comment: "subroutine" isn't a common term, based on your last code block I believe you actually meant to say a static class method? A subroutine is a very old way of saying "function", it isn't an OOP specific term and may not mean what you think it means in common use. Your question also isn't very clear, nor is what it is that you consider OOP conventions ( none of your code is OOP, it's using classes yes, but none of it is object oriented ). I also see that you are trying to call a dynamic method from a static method, and that you are also calling a static method as if it's a non-class function

Comment: to be clear, all the code in your question is imperative procedural code, the classes are not object oriented, they do nothing more than namespace the functions, which would be better done by using PHP namespaces. Classes for the sake of classes do not make life easier, and unless you intend to create multiple instances of something that has internal state/variables then you are building bad habits here. I would also recommend you watch the google clean code videos on global state, static methods as used here are a dangerous anti-pattern and are difficult to test or çreate mocks

Comment: As an aside, this could all be done using modern WordPress APIs with a single block, rendered in PHP, with variations registered for each variant.

Comment: @jcropp "which doesn't work because it doesn't follow OOP conventions" - and it could be made to work by declaring the helper function as a static method, then use `self::foo_bar_subroutine()` from within your shortcode functions. Or you could use an instance-getter method without declaring `foo_bar_subroutine` as static. But then can't the shortcode functions just be non-static methods? Or even global functions? What specific reasons you have for making them static class methods? Just to "group" them in the same class? Then why not use namespace instead?